# every loop run new array should create-Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make key and value in array in jquery but in loop is adding as object not as new array or key.

```
$.each($("input[type='time']"), function(){
             var check = $(this).attr('id'); 
              if(checkboxid==check)
              {     
           timeid.push($(this).attr('id'));
           timevalue.push($(this).val());
              }
            });
  $.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data:  "Weekend="+myCheckboxes+"&"+timeid+"="+timevalue,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data!=1)
            {
                alert('Done');
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Not Ok");
            }  
        }
   });
```

Comment: if you `console.log( timeid )` before `$.ajax`, does it show as an array?

Comment: @ GrafiCode Studio yes but it is including value only in one array. I want key=>value but its giving keykey=>valuevalue

Comment: in your loop: `timeid[ $(this).attr('id') ] = $(this).val();`

Comment: @ GrafiCode Studio not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an array object. Try the following

HTML

```
<input id="appt-time1" type="time" name="appt-time" value="13:30">
<input id="appt-time2" type="time" name="appt-time" value="01:30">
<input id="appt-time3" type="time" name="appt-time" value="02:30">
<input id="appt-time4" type="time" name="appt-time" value="03:30">
<input id="appt-time5" type="time" name="appt-time" value="04:30">
```

JQuery

```
$(function () {
    var timevalue = [];
    $.each($("input[type='time']"), function () {            
        timevalue.push({ id: $(this).attr('id'), value: $(this).val() });
    });

    for (i = 0; i < timevalue.length; i++) {
        console.log("ID: " + timevalue[i].id + " Value: " + timevalue[i].value);
    }
});
```